# Java Card 3 Platform development kit is installed failed

Tags: java

I am new to Java Card development. During in the installation of development kit, I have some troubles and have no idea.

First of all, I downloaded the Java Card Platform from Oracle and install it step by step according to:  https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/guide/eclipse_java_card_plug-in.htm#JCUGC126

But during installation the following error appeared:

[image]

I　checked that the path of `JC_classic_HOME` is okay. Maybe the problem is caused by the incompatibility of the Java Card Platform and JCOP. So, I unload the JCOP and install it again, but the error also exist.

Just as the guide said: https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/guide/install_and_setup_the_development_kit.htm#JCUGC118

java version "1.8.0_111"
gcc version  5.3.0
eclipse IDE version 3.5.1
Apache version 1.9.7.

I know eclipse IDE is optional. My classmate used Visual Studio 2010、 gradle and JCDK3.0.3 build the project. But my object need eclipse IDE.

I have no idea, and I want someone give me some advice. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

What version of JDK and Eclipse are you using?

According to the [user guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/guide/install_and_setup_the_development_kit.htm#JCUGC118), JDK 7(8) and Eclipse Luna are recommended

I'm using the recommended version of `JDK` and `Eclipse`, didn't encounter the error above. Perhaps, you could take a try!

Comment: Thank you! You give me the confidence to have a try. I used recommended version of JDK and  Eclipse IDE too, but failed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I reinstall the Eclipse IDE, and the error disappeared. I believe it is incompatibility with JCOP.

Comment: @Johna congratulations.